# PHP Fatal error: Class 'gdlr_admin_option' not found in path/to/gdlr_hotel_plugin/plugin_option.php line 40

Tags: wordpress

Am geeting a WordPress error on my wordpresswebsite after it being online for a few minutes hrs. saying the website is experiencing some technical difficulties

have tried to reupload the code more than ones but after some time, it gives me the WordPress error

```
if( !function_exists('gdlr_create_hotel_admin_option') ){

    function gdlr_create_hotel_admin_option(){
        global $hotel_option, $gdlr_sidebar_controller;

        new gdlr_admin_option( 

            // admin option attribute
            array(
                'page_title' => __('Hotel Option', 'gdlr-hotel'),
                'menu_title' => __('Hotel Option', 'gdlr-hotel'),
                'menu_slug' => 'hotel_option',
                'save_option' => 'gdlr_hotel_option',
                'role' => 'edit_theme_options',
                'position' => 83,
            ),

            // admin option setting
            array(
                // general menu
                'general' => array(
                    'title' => __('General', 'gdlr-hotel'),
                    'icon' => GDLR_PATH . '/include/images/icon-general.png',
                    'options' => array(

                        'general-option' => array(
                            'title' => __('General Option', 'gdlr-hotel'),
                            'options' => array(
                                'booking-money-format' => array(
                                    'title' => __('Money Display Format', 'gdlr-hotel'),
                                    'type' => 'text',   
                                    'default' => '$NUMBER',
                                ),
                                'enable-hotel-branch' => array(
                                    'title' => __('Enable Hotel Branch ( Using Category )', 'gdlr-hotel'),
                                    'type' => 'checkbox',   
                                    'default' => 'disable'
                                ),
                                'enable-adult-child-option' => array(
                                    'title' => __('Enable Adult - Children Option', 'gdlr-hotel'),
                                    'type' => 'checkbox',   
                                    'default' => 'enable'
                                ),
                                'preserve-booking-room' => array(
                                    'title' => __('Preserve The Room After', 'gdlr-hotel'),
                                    'type' => 'combobox',   
                                    'options' => array(
                                        'paid' => __('Paid for room', 'gdlr-hotel'),
                                        'booking' => __('Booking for room', 'gdlr-hotel')
                                    )
                                ),
                                'booking-price-display' => array(
                                    'title' => __('Booking Price Display', 'gdlr-hotel'),
                                    'type' => 'combobox',   
                                    'options' => array(
                                        'start-from' => __('Start From', 'gdlr-hotel'),
                                        'full-price' => __('Full Price', 'gdlr-hotel')
                                    )
                                ),
                                'booking-vat-amount' => ar
```

Comment: PHP is telling you that it can't find the class `gdlr_admin_option`. Make sure that: 1) the file actually exists, 2) it's readable by PHP, and 3) the file is actually being included/required by the plugin somewhere.

Comment: in the include folder, I can only see a  `gdlr-admin-option.php` file. Also in the function.pp file, ` `include_once( 'include/gdlr-admin-option.php');
 include_once( 'include/gdlr-plugin-option.php');
 include_once( 'include/gdlr-font-controls.php');`